# (J)Table doesn't sort despite having enabled auto-row-sorter and using comparable data

Tags: java, swing, scala, jtable, tablerowsorter

I can't get the following Swing table view to be sortable. While I do get the little triangles on the column headers flipping, the table content is not refreshed any differently depending on the sort status:

```
import scala.swing._

val data = Array(
  Array("a", 4, 8.9),
  Array("b", 7, 2.3),
  Array("c", 1, 5.6)
).map(_.map(_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]))

val m = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(data, 
  Array[AnyRef]("string", "int", "double")) {

   override def getColumnClass(c: Int): Class[_] = c match {
     case 0 => classOf[java.lang.String ]
     case 1 => classOf[java.lang.Integer]
     case 2 => classOf[java.lang.Double ]
   }
}

val t = new Table
t.model = m
t.peer.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)

new Frame {
  contents = new ScrollPane(t)
  pack().centerOnScreen()
  open()
}
```

[image]

I have tested this with different look-and-feels (screenshot shows Nimbus) and JDKs (OpenJDK 6, OpenJDK 7). Furthermore, I have a custom tree-table component that sorts without problems, so the mistake must lie somewhere above.

Comment: not Scala user but you can try to create, override RowSorter with toggleSortOrder instead of setAutoCreateRowSorter(true), then is possible to test if the methods from RowSorter, DefaultTableModel and JTable are accesible and returns value that make the sence

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is some bug in Scala-Swing. Why am I not surprised?!

```
import scala.swing._

type I = java.lang.Integer
type D = java.lang.Double

val data = Array[Array[Object]](
  Array("a", 4:I, 8.9:D),
  Array("b", 7:I, 2.3:D),
  Array("c", 1:I, 5.6:D)
)

val m = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(data, 
  Array[AnyRef]("string", "int", "double")) {

  override def getColumnClass(c: Int): Class[_] = data(0)(c).getClass
}

val tj = new javax.swing.JTable(m)  // !!!
tj.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)
val t = Component.wrap(tj)          // !!!

new Frame {
  contents = new ScrollPane(t)
  pack().centerOnScreen()
  open()
}
```

It might be [this bug](https://github.com/scala/scala-swing/issues/30) although the title says column-sorting is affected (the texts suggests the submitter is talking about row sorting). My guess is that the renderer-wrapping is broken in terms of `viewToModel`/`modelToView`.

---

**Edit**: Confirmed. All it takes is

```
val t = new Table {
  // disable broken renderer
  override lazy val peer: JTable = new JTable with SuperMixin
}
```